# making a font awesome icon circle

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

```
 <div class="team-icon">
            <ul>
                <li class="fab fa-facebook" style="border-radius: 50%"></li>
                <li class="fab fa-twitter-square"></li>
                <li class="fab fa-google-plus"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

This is my code, but border-radius doesn't work. I want to make the icons circle.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What `icons circle`?

Comment: I want to make a web page similar to the other page

Comment: What other page?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.team-icon ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
}

.team-icon li {
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

.team-icon a {
    min-width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="team-icon">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fab fa-google-plus"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a border to display, you need to specify a border style in your style tag, i.e.

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

Another thing to keep in mind, your border radius style might need to be declared in another dimension like ems or pxs. Make sure your li elements have a width, too.

Answer (score 0):

You need a background-color or a border displayed

```
<ul>
    <li style=“border-radius:5px;border:1px solid black;width:10%;”>List Item</li>
</ul>
```

I also recommend you change the width of the list element because it’s default is 100% and to use pixels instead of percentage for your border radius.